# install vxworks on vortex 86d

Tags: embedded, vxworks

I wonder by any chance is there a way to install vxworks on [vdx86d(vdx6354)](http://www.emacinc.com/products/pc_compatible_sbcs/VDX-6354)? I searched a lot on the net and did not find NO to this question, but no manual or help could be find by me. anybody did this before and know how to do it?

Comment: You should specify which version of VxWorks you intend to deploy.

Comment: You should also specify the boot media/source you wish to use.

Comment: Cilfford the latest version of vxworks that could work on vdx86d is the purpose and I use DOM(hard) or usb flash to boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VxWorks certainly runs on PC architecture x86 targets; there is probably already a suitable 80486 BSP that will suit this board.  You can search for a suitable BSP [here](https://bsp.windriver.com/index.php?bsp&on=list&type=architecture&value=x86/Pentium/IA-32/IA-64). There is only one BSP explicitly listed for 486 targetted at VxWorks 5.4/Tornado 2.0 - so it is as antique as 486 architecture itself.  VxWorks 6.9 however has a [single unified BSP for x86](https://bsp.windriver.com/index.php?bsp&on=details&bsp=12600) which will no doubt work with your board.

VxWorks is not "installed" as such in the same way as a GPOS such as Linux or Windows; rather you link your application with the VxWorks libraries to create an application image that runs directly on boot.  How the bootstrap process works varies between architectures and hardware implementation, but as a generic PC architecture board, booting a VxWorks application on your board will be the same as any other PC target.  As such what you need to look for are directions on booting VxWorks on PC architecture rather then being specific about your actual board.

On PC architecture you can boot from mass-storage, or from a network server.  Booting via a network connection is the normal method during debug/development.  A great deal of the information available is for older versions of VxWorks.  However it seems that it is possible to boot VxWorks via a VxWorks specific bootstrap, or from a generic PC bootloader such a s U-Boot.

Ultimately [Wind River Support](http://www.windriver.com/support/) is probably a good starting point.

Comment: How can I download BSP without having a license or username in windriver systems website? I googled and found nothing!

Comment: @amin : I cannot advise you on breaching the licence terms required by the vendor.